# Using an array technique for manipulating individual pixels on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sprite-kit

A programmer told me that he used an array technique for manipulating individual pixels on screen to attain a very specific look in his (Java?) game. This is his outcome:
[image]
<sub>(source: [awkwardknight.com](http://awkwardknight.com/StayGame/GIFs/day-night_cycle3.gif))</sub>

That is the exact same thing I am trying to get: the 'lightsource' (or just a general area) that nullifies the tinted layer around it to make it seem like light is illuminating its vicinity. This is the programmers exact words:
"The way Caelis renders uses a pixel array representing each pixel on the screen and using a function, you can iterate and darken/lighten whatever you want."

I can't understand how to do this. I've never done anything like this. Right now I have an 'SKShapeNode' serving as my tint layer with the alpha varying on time of day (which I get from 'NSDate'). But I can't change individual pixel alphas.

Can someone please explain how to write such a function? Maybe some example code? Would be very appreciated since I don't know how to write a custom shader either U_U

Comment: The solution is to go learn to write "a custom shader". Anything else you try to do is going to be a waste of time. This is what GPUs are for.

Comment: @Jessy - I disagree. How can a custom shader bring about the street lights glow or the blinking stars? What about the transition from day to night?

Comment: I can't tell if your question is rhetorical. You could ask individual questions on Stack Overflow, and I'd try to help, but from your propagation of the "nightmare" nonsense below, I don't think you're actually interested in learning to do this right.

Comment: I am interested in learning it. I want to be a better programmer, but currently I have no time. But thanks to the answers to this question I now know where to head when I do get the time :D

Comment: Have you considered using an `SKCropNode` for each light?

Comment: I have now. Going to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating every single pixel (or point) on the screen sounds like an extremely inefficient way of doing things.

To achieve the day/night effect in the animation, I suggest you create 2 or more layers. One for day, one for night and perhaps one for the transition. Then you place each in the view with different zPositions. To transition from one "ambiance" to another, use a timed alpha fade in for the new and fade out for the old.

Comment: That's the technique I use now. I guess I really will have to go learn to write a custom shader. *cries*

Comment: @Krekin - I second that. Custom shaders are a nightmare to work with.

Comment: From the fear of having to write a custom shader came a semi-eureka moment! I'm just going to use your suggestion with the layers but I will also add 1 extra layer on top of all layers that will have painted light on it in the locations of lightposts & such. I'll also need to throw out the idea of the player using a flashlight. Or any portable light source for that matter.